# Check if a game center account is logged in

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I am having some troubles with my game center implementation.
Is there a piece of code that can check if the users game center account is logged in?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I manually prompt the user to log in to Game Center on iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781501/can-i-manually-prompt-the-user-to-log-in-to-game-center-on-ios-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check it like this:

```
if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated)
{
  // user logged in
}
```